# The URL for feeds in chat gets mangled when it contains spaces and special characters

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, hot-questions, feed

I'm trying to [set up a feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314073/158100) in a chat room. The URL has a query parameter, and I tried to stay close to what is allowed in the [OData](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html) specification.

It turns out that SE chat is a bit more restrictive. For example, this URL:

```
https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/+?filter=tags contains 'number'
```

does get posted correctly to the chat web server:

```
feedUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me%2Fhnq%2F%2B%3Ffilter%3Dtags+contains+%27number%27
```

but when the server returns the response page, the URL is reduced to:

```
https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/+?filter=tagscontainsnumber
```

This is not a visual glitch as on my server as I see calls being done with `tagscontainsnumber`, so this is what ended up being stored as URL for the SE chat bot to use.

I've found that I can work around this issue by doing the URL encoding upfront:

```
https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/+?filter=tags%20contains%20%27number%27
```

which does give me a feed with the applied filter:

[image: click the image to jump to the chat message. This image shows: chat message: rene has made a change to the feeds chat message: rene has made a change to the feeds chat message: one box of a question on codegolf with the tag number]

I'm not sure why the URL needs to go through this sanitizing step on the chat server, specially if the URL itself doesn't seem to be causing problems or being blocked when using the workaround.

I know Feed URLs are [restricted on length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139030/chat-feed-bot-chokes-on-long-urls) and [Feeds do have encoding weirdness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278415) but this is only slightly related.

For now I'm going to tag this as both [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as I expect this to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). I propose to consider three options and request one to be selected and implemented:

- Add a warning / error message if you enter "illegal" characters in the `feedUrl` field
- URL Encode the `feedUrl` before it is posted to the server
- Do not sanitize the URL on the server.

If none of these can or will be implemented, I'll accept an answer that shares the implementation details so that it is less of a surprise what happens.